# How to store a list of 'ModelBase' object in a view ('ModelBase' object is not subscriptable)

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build an app with Django where you can build different foods based on ingredients you can previously create.

The way the user does this is by selecting each `Ingredient` for the `Food`. Note that one request is sent by each `Ingredient` selection.

models.py:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    """User selects different instances of this model, to build instances of FoodDetail, it can be, for instance: 'Meat'."""
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, null=False, default=0.00)
    stock = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=3, null=False, default=0.000)


class Food(models.Model):
    """The new food the user will create once it has finished the Ingredients selection. For instance, 'Burger'."""
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, null=False)


class FoodIngredient(models.Model):
    """Instance of an ingredient (e.g. 'Bread') of a specific instance of Food (e.g. 'Burger')."""
    food = models.ForeignKey(Food, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=3, default=0.000, null=False)
```

So you can create any ingredients, and then use them to build different foods.
Now imagine that user sends one `FoodIngredient` per request, and I need to accumulate them in the `view`, so that I can submit the new `Food` with its `FoodIngredient`s to the database in a single transaction.

The error I'm getting is:

```
TypeError at /Foods/creation
'ModelBase' object is not subscriptable
```

The code that is making this trouble is:

```
def get_ingredients_in_session(request):
    ingredients = []  # The list to be returned
    if 'ingredients' in request.session and request.session['ingredients'].__len__() > 0: 
        for k, v in request.session['ingredients'].items():  # k is the ingredient id and v is the quantity chosen
            ingredient = Ingredient.objects.get(account__id=request.session['id_account'], id=k)
            det = build_det(ingredient, v)  # This function builds a FoodIngredient from an Ingredient and returns it to the variable 'det'
            ingredients.append(det[:])  # This line is having the error
    return ingredients
```

This function is used to display in the `view` a summary of the ingredients (and the quantity of heach of them) that user is currently choosing for its new `Food`. How can I solve this?
Save my project and prevent me to move to Spring... (haha)

*EDIT: Post the build_det function.*

```
def build_det(ingredient, v):
    det = FoodIngredient  
    det.ingredient = ingredient
    det.quantity = Decimal(v)
    return det
```

Comment: post the build_det function.

Comment: I added it if you want to check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `det = FoodIngredient` to `det = FoodIngredient()`
the first produces a type instance(a ModelBase object) and the second produces a constructed instance(a record in the FoodIngredient table)

add `det.save()` to store the new instance in the database. Without this call your changes will not persist

the code does not return a dictionary or an array so the `ingredients.append(det[:])` must be rewritten as `ingredients.append(det)`